# Iterating though nested JSON values with python

Tags: python, json

I want to be able to iterate through nested values in a JSON file and add them to a list.

For example, I want to find the values contained in each instance of *Test* below.

```
 A= {"Tags": [
                {
                    "Item":{
                        "Test":"mouse",
                    },
                },
                {
                    "Item":{
                        "Test":"dog",
                    },
                },
                {
                    "Item":{
                        "Test":"cat",
                    },
                },
                {
                    "Item":{
                        "Test":"dog",
                    },
                }
            ]
        }
```

I can select values individually like so:

```
print(A['Tags'][1]['Item']['Test'])
```

But I can't iterate over the entire JSON file.

Comment: iterate over `item` in A['Tags']. It's just a list and your each `item` is a dictionary and can access any field you want.

Comment: `for item in A['Tags']: ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This iterates over the whole and appends each value to a list.

```py
output = list()

for tag in A['Tags']:
    output.append(tag['Item']['Test'])
```

If you're worried about missing values, the following will correct for that.

```py
output = list()

for tag in A['Tags']:
    if item := tag.get('Item', dict()).get('Test'):
        output.append(item)
```

Output:

```
['mouse', 'dog', 'cat', 'dog']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for tag in A['Tags']:
    print(tag['Item']['Test'])
```

`A['Tags']` is just a list of objects/dictionary, which is referred by `tag` and then you can access any value inside the object via a key.

Answer (score 0):

**I have a simpler method: use the jsonpath package**

**You can learn jsonpath, which is very convenient, but the disadvantage is that it is slow**

```
from jsonpath import jsonpath

A = {"Tags": [
    {
        "Item": {
            "Test": "mouse",
        },
    },
    {
        "Item": {
            "Test": "dog",
        },
    },
    {
        "Item": {
            "Test": "cat",
        },
    },
    {
        "Item": {
            "Test": "dog",
        },
    }
]
}

print(jsonpath(A, "$..Test"))
```

out

```
['mouse', 'dog', 'cat', 'dog']
```

Comment: One can also use `jmespath`. I think it is a much more capable library than jsonpath. https://jmespath.org/